# Is $f$ bijective on$\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ a function from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$. Study if $f$ does have an inverse in whole $\mathbb{R}^2$?

**My approach:** Since $\det(Df(x,y))=(2x)(2x)-(-2y)(2y)=4x^2+4y^2\neq 0$ for $x,y\neq 0$ then $f$ is locally invertible, for any $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. But how can I know if this inverse function is the same for all the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Thanks!

Comment: $f(1,0)=f(-1,0)$, so $f$ is not injective.

Comment: It doesn't, $f(a,b)=f(-a,-b)$.

Comment: Thanks!! Now I see how to proceed!

Answer (score 5):

**Hints:**

1. Look for two points (perhaps with small integer coordinates) to show that it is not injective.
2. A deeper hint: do you know complex numbers? What is $(x+iy)^2$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: you have something squared, which often tends to not be injective. Try to find two points (there are some fairly easy ones) to disprove that it is injective.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2, 2xy)$ is the Real version of the Complex function $f(z)=z^2$. Its inverse is only a local one, since $f(z)=f(-z)$, and this *local* inverse is the square root function, which is not 1-1.